# Hack css font-size for Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css

I know that each browser has default css.

I have an header of my site and I want to define different font-size in each browser.

so I have this style:

```
.FontSize { 14px; }
```

and this element:

```
<span class="FontSize">text</span>
```

For Chrome I want to set:

```
font-size: 12px;
```

For firefox I want to set:

```
font-size: 12px;
```

I read that I hack the css, so this is my css file:

CSS FILE:

```
.FontSize { 14px; }

/* Chrome */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .FontSize {font-size:12px;}
}

/* Firefox */
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .FontSize {
     font-size:12px;
  }
}
```

but it doesn't change the font-size in these browsers (Chrome and Firefox)..

Any help appreciated!

Comment: On the fly I would say you could use JavaScript for reading the browsers _USER AGENT_. Depending on the _USER AGENT_ you could set a CSS style for a specific browser

Comment: ... or you could just use a CSS reset to nuke the browser-specific styling just set it once.

Comment: @alonshmiel i have a ready answer if you are ready to work with javascript...

Comment: @cuSK, Thank you but with no JS.

pbaldauf, thank you..

RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, CSS reset causes the header to get strange..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **chrome** only css:

```css
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .FontSize  { font-size: 12px; }
}
```

For **firefox** only css:

```css
.FontSize,  x:-moz-any-link  { font-size: 12px; }
```

There is slight error in your snippet. The above mentioned will solve your problem.

Read Paul Rish's [Browser CSS hacks](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/) for more tricks.